# What are other ways to express gratitude in German?

Tags: english-to-german, expression

In conversational contexts, I've often found myself wanting to express gratitude in a bit more of an exciting way than *Danke*. I'm not talking about *vielen Dank*, *tausend Dank* etc.

More personal phrases like:

> That's very kind of you.
>
> You are too sweet!
>
> I really appreciate that.
>
> That means a lot to me."

Comment: Relevant cultural differences: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38177/how-do-you-know-if-americans-genuinely-literally-mean-what-they-say, especially the quoted paragraph in the accepted answer. What is perfectly normal for a speaker whose first language is English sounds to a German like you're pulling their leg; a standard German thank you sounds like a lackluster white lie to an English speaker,

Answer (score 4):

**Hier paar Beispiele für verschiedene Gelegenheiten:**

Informell/ vorallem zu Frauen/Kindern/sehr nahestehenden Menschen:

> Vielen Dank, wie lieb von dir!
>
> Das ist so lieb/nett!
>
> Das ist (ganz) lieb/nett von dir. = That's so sweet of you.

Informell, geschlechts-/altersunabhängig:

> Vielen Dank, dass du das extra für mich getan hast!
>
> Das bedeutet mir sehr viel. = That means a lot to me.

Kann auch formell genutzt werden:

> Ich weiß das wirklich zu schätzen. = I really appreciate that.
>
> Vielen Dank, das ist sehr freundlich/großzügig von Ihnen.

Comment: Du hast informell geschrieben. z.B kann man nicht sagen; **Vielen Dank, wie lieb von Ihnen**?

Comment: @Ad Infinitum, zumindest mit "lieb" würde ich das lassen.

Comment: Alles klar. Danke schön.

Comment: @Ad Infinitum, auch "nett" klingt für mich komisch. Ich würde dann z.B. "freundlich" nehmen

Comment: Das ist sehr freundlich von Ihnen?

Comment: @Ad Infinitum, ja. Ich habe auch meine Antwort diesbezüglich editiert.

Comment: vielen Dank, wie lieb von Dir :)

Answer (score 0):

"I really appreciate that."  Das weiß ich sehr zu schätzen.

"That means a lot to me." Das bedeutet mir sehr viel.

"That's very kind of you." Wie nett von Dir./ Wie zuvorkommend

"That leaves me speechless" Das macht mich sprachlos.

All of those are best used with some form on Danke/Danke schön etc. which you said you know.

Comment: Ohne Kontekt würde ich "Das macht mich sprachlos." nicht als Zeichen des Danks verstehen, eher das Gegenteil.

Comment: @Iris Wenn ich mich bedanken will würde ich all die genannten Vorschläge noch mit einem Danke, vielen Dank o.ä. kombinieren.

Comment: Aber auch dann würde ich eher sagen, "Diese Geste/deine Selbstlosigkeit/deine Großzügigkeit macht mich sprachlos".

Comment: @Iris I would perceive either of "Diese Geste/deine Selbstlosigkeit/deine Großzügigkeit macht mich sprachlos" far to exalted in a personal context to be anything but ironic.